# What is "tap" on mobile platform?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

What does the word "tap" mean on mobile platform? I can see there is `IsTapEnabled` property on `UI.Element(s)`, however I don't understand what kind of action is "tap". What is difference between "tap" and "pressed"?

Answer (score 0):

`Pressed` event is published when you start touching a control (= your finger starts to touch the control on the screen).

`Tap` event is published after you release the touch from the control (= remove your finger from the screen). It's the equivalent of `Clicked` in desktop applications.

Comment: Do we have any reference point for that? Link to documentation? Thanks